# How to efficiently remove (assign NULL) many objects with similar names in a single call

Tags: r, memory-management

I have a bunch of data tables in R (say: dt1, dt2, dt3, etc.) that I want to remove from memory to clear up space. I have often used the following:

```
dt1 <- NULL
dt2 <- NULL
dt3 <- NULL
```

However, if I have many data tables this becomes a lot of lines. Is there a way to do this in one line?

Side question: I believe using NULL is a faster way to clear the space but still leaves the object in memory versus using `rm(dt1)` which actually clears the memory assignment of the object but does take longer.

Comment: One way is `dt1 <- dt2 <- dt3 <- NULL`. Is the time taken by `rm` such a big deal? How many microseconds?

Comment: `rm(list = c("dt1", "dt2", "dt3"))` might do the job. If you want to remove everything in your env you could try `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), "dt2"))` to remove everything except `dt2`

Comment: I could be wrong about time being the issue with `rm()`. There was something I read somewhere about `<- NULL` being preferred to `rm()`.

Comment: my personal preference is `rm(dt1,dt2,dt3)` followed by `gc()` it clears the data tables and it clears the memory of both the tables and any hanging intermediates that were used in manipulations that are still lingering in memory.

Answer (score 4):

This will remove all dataframes that start with 'dt'.

If you use table naming convention strategically, you can insert this wherever you'd like and clear your space.

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^dt"))
```